# What's causing our app to try and find a file named "BEMR, Culture=neutral"?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, filenotfoundexception

We've got a new WPF app we've written, that doesn't get any further than the landing screen. Once a user clicks on a button to do something they're confronted with an error that reads like this:

> An Error occurred:Set property
>   'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'BEMR, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

(Our app is named BEMR.)

Yes, there is no file by that name. I searched throughout the whole project and besides the string "BEMR, Culture=neutral" being in EF's EDMX files, the only other place that string appears is in the App.Config file:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

It most certainly is not a file, just a reference to the culture that EF is using.

So, what is causing our app to try and find a file by that name?

Comment: maybe some dll is not the latest? We had similar issue before. It turns out one of the dll was not updated correctly.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the "or one of its dependencies" portion of the error message; is there any missing dependency?  This will probably help: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: I'll look to see if the dll's are up to date. And will also look for other errors. Thanks, urlreader and Eric.

Comment: You could try this tool to find the cause of the issue: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MykolaTarasyuk.ReferenceConflictsAnalyser

Comment: My colleague found the issue. A resource dictionary was wrongly specified. It was: <ResourceDictionary Source="/BEMR;component/Assets/PrintResources.xaml" />. It should have been: <ResourceDictionary Source="../BEMR;component/Assets/PrintResources.xaml" />

Thank you all for your help!